# Route all traffic from VPN through another interface

Tags: vpn, routing

I have two Linux servers, one is "main" with Pritunl VPN and the other one meant to be "exit point".
Purpose of this is the aggregating connection to the client on the "main" server with higher specs and push the traffic through the "exit point" server.
Between those, tho servers is another VPN set up (using [vpncloud](https://github.com/dswd/vpncloud)).

How to achieve pushing all connection from the PritunlVPN to the second server (and there to the internet), so users can access the internet only through exit-point server?
*PritunlVPN connection should be still established through the main server.*

**Server one ("main"):** 
eth0 - 1.2.3.100 - incomming VPN connections, internet 
tun5 (tunX) - 10.0.60.1 - PritunlVPN interface 
vpncloud0 - 172.16.0.1 - VPN between servers (using [vpncloud](https://github.com/dswd/vpncloud))

```
enter codenter code heree heredefault via 1.2.3.4 dev eth0 proto static 
10.0.60.0/24 dev tun5 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.60.1 
10.16.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.16.0.5 
1.2.3.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 1.2.3.100 
172.16.0.0/24 dev vpncloud0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.1
```

**Server two ("exit-point"):** 
eth0 - 4.5.6.100 - internet 
vpncloud0 - 172.16.0.2 - VPN between servers (using [vpncloud](https://github.com/dswd/vpncloud))

```
default via 4.5.6.7 dev eth0 proto static 
4.5.6.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 4.5.6.100
172.16.0.0/24 dev vpncloud0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.2
```

How to achieve this?

[Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENmRn.jpg)

Comment: It is hard to relate your diagrams and your text in the answer. Could you please use exactly same names and other labelling for same items there and here? What line represents "PrinutlVPN" (at least, which interface it is)? What are the dashed arrows?

Comment: Hi @NikitaKipriyanov, I tried keep consistent interface naming (only tunX refers to tun5 in this case), also Pritunl interface is defined as tun5 (tunX).
But I updated the diagram, added note where exactly stands PritunlVPN. Dashed arrows were supposed to represent "to the internet" links, I deleted them.
Please let me know if it is more clear now.